# How to set different default email addresses for author and committer?

Tags: git

The git repository I'm working with only allows commits from certain users. This is enforced by verification of the committer email field and rejection of any commits from unknown email addresses.

So I'm forced to commit with a special email address but I'd still like to use my regular email address as "author" email. The "user email" which I can set through my git client seems to be used for both author and committer addresses, but I want these to be different for each commit to this repository.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many graphical git clients do not let you configure all available settings in the UI.

Author and committer can be set independently by setting the `author.email` and `committer.email` to different values like this:

```
git config --local author.email me@example.org
git config --local committer.email user@example.com
```

The `author.name` for `committer.name` can be set in the same way. These values will then be used instead of the regular `user.name` and `user.email` properties.

For details see: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-authorname